# Access a column from another table in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables as Page and Country in many to many relationship. I have to display a page according to slug and locale passed in my route. The locale field is in Country table. How can i access it in PageController

Here are my Schemas for both tables

```
CREATE TABLE `countries` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL, `cname` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `lname` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `locale` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL, `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `updated_at` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, `slug` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )

CREATE TABLE `pages` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `slug` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
```

Here is the method i am using

```
public function findBySlugAndLocale($slug,$locale)
{
    return $this->model->where('slug', str_slug(trim($slug)))->where('countries',str_slug(trim($locale)))->first();
}
```

In above method the slug and locale are coming from route so here is my route

```
  Route::get('/{slug}/{locale}', ['as' => 'show','uses' => 'HomeController@findBySlugAndLocale']);
```

I want a query something like this

```
select * from `pages` where `slug` = home and `countries` = en
```

Here are my Models:

```
class Country extends  Basemodel {

protected $table = "countries";

public function pages() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Page', 'country_page', 'country_id', 'page_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

}

```
class Page extends  Basemodel {

protected $table = "pages";

public function countries() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Country', 'country_page', 'page_id', 'country_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

}

Comment: Please some code paste here

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd Please have a look

Comment: you get any error ?

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'countries' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `pages` where `slug` = home and `countries` = en limit 1)`

Comment: Where is your model OR table relationship?

Comment: Check i have edited

Comment: Please follow this link(https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#Many%20To%20Many)

Comment: And i think you should use class Country extends  Model instead of class Country extends  Basemodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I solved the above using join... Here is the query... It may help someone with the same issue

```
public function findBySlugAndLocale($slug,$locale)
{
    $results = $this->model
        ->join('country_page', 'pages.id', '=', 'country_page.page_id')
        ->join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'country_page.country_id')
        ->where('pages.slug', '=', $slug)
        ->where('countries.locale', '=', $locale)
        ->first();
    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly and you want to query the pages table based on a locale in the countries table you'll need to use `whereHas`:

```
return $this->model
    ->where('slug', str_slug(trim($slug)))
    ->whereHas('countries', function ($query) use ($locale) {
        $query->where('locale', str_slug(trim($locale)));
    })->first();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Getting pages:null

Comment: @NehaSacher Do you definitely have data in your database that would satisfy the query?

Comment: @NehaSacher The only difference between my answer and your answer is that your answer doesn't seem to wrap the values in `str_slug` and `trim`. The result should be exactly the same though.